# How do I virtualize my windows drive in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am running a dual boot system. In parallels on my mac, I am able to view my bootcamp partition live in a virtual machine. Is there a tool to do this in ubuntu?

Comment: I see you tagged VirtualBox. Did you try it and get stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible in VirtualBox. Check out [Section 9.9.1](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp57804112) from the VirtualBox manual, "Using a raw host hard disk from a guest." You'll want to look at the subsection 9.9.1.2, "Access to individual physical hard disk partitions."